# how to connect to c# rest api from ionic 2 mobile app?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ionic2

I don't have any clue how to access asp.net web api from ionic 2 mobile application.

Any solution to solve this issue will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to do an http request to say the least. Here is an article which demonstrates working with an api. I unfortunately have no way to test any of this. I hope it helps.
 https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/